# Lang's proof that a subgroup of index 2 is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, proof-explanation

In Lang's Algebra, he gives the following in an example

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of index 2.  Then $H$ is normal in $G$

I've been working through his proof, and here is how I've been able to understand it

> Note that $H$ is contained in its normaliser $N_H$, so the index of $N_H$ in $G$ is 1 or 2.  If it is 1 then $N_H=G$ and $H$ is normal and we are done.  If it is 2 (i.e. $H$ is not normal since $N_H=H$), let $G$ operate by conjugation on the set of \hl{subgroups}.  The orbit of $H$ under $G$ has 2 elements (since the order of the orbit is equal to the index $(G:G_s)$, and in this case the isotropy group is equal to the normaliser which has index 2 by hypothesis).  The action of $G$ on the orbit of $H$ under $G$ gives a homomorphism of $G$ into the group of permutations of 2 elements (definition \ref{Chpt 1 definition of action/operation of group on set}).  This means there is one conjugate of $H$ unequal to $H$ (since we know $G$ is homomorphic to permutations of two elements, and the permutation of two elements is either "stay the same" or "swap", so one of them is not the identity).  Therefore, the kernel of our homomorphism is normal (since it is the kernel of an isomorphism), **of index 2 (since the index of $N_H$ is 2, so it at most can be 2 but greater than 1 else all subgroups will be normal)**, and therefore equal to $H$.  This would imply that $H$ is normal, which is a contradiction.

My reasoning for the part in bold feels a bit shaky to me, but I'm not sure how he's concluded that the kernel is index 2.  Surely the case where exactly half of $G$ is the identity and the other half is the swapping operation is too ideal to be taken generally?  Also, is my reasoning for the proof correct?  Lang's proof was very short and I've tried to fill in some of what I think the reasoning is myself but I'm not sure if it is correct.

Comment: @AnneBauval: That looks more like an answer than a comment to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel of our homomorphism is normal since it is the kernel of an *homo*morphism.

It is of index $2$ because it is $N_H$ and we assumed the index of $N_H$ is $2.$

And therefore equal to $H$ because $H⊂N_H$ and $H$ is also of index $2.$